# Java's Queue cannot specify limited size, so what's difference between "add" and "offer"

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, linked-list, queue

**Java's Queue**:
The difference between "add" and "offer" is that if the queue has been full, the "add" will cause the Exception, and "offer" just return false.

**But my question is** "when the queue can be full"?
It seems that there is no size-fixed queue in standard java, and the queue has no method to specify the size. 
So if we continue to add/offer the element into queue, the queue will be **extended automatically**.

- If that is true, what's the difference between "add" and "offer" when
  we use it.
- If that is not true, how to specify the max size of a queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface *allows* for implementations with a limited size. It does not *require* implementations to have a size bound by forcing implementations to have a `setSize` method.

See for instance [`ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#ArrayBlockingQueue%28int%29).

---

> *So if we continue to add/offer the element into queue, the queue will be extended automatically.*

No, a `Queue` implementation is not required to grow automatically.

Comment: Thanks @aioobe, get it. This question confused me for a long while, now you remind me that "the interface is just interface, the implementations may not have to implement the method(optional)", and you also let me recall another thing, java's interface has no "require"/"optional" keyword(some language such as Objective-C has), that means if we want to do something like that, we need use abstract class or let interface extends interface.....so thank you so much.

Comment: @Zhaonan, A class that `implements Queue` _is_ required to implement all of the Queue methods, but the contract (i.e., the javadoc for `Queue`) permits some freedom in _how_ the class implements them.  So for example, a non-blocking Queue implementation _must_ have an add() method _and_ an offer() method, but it's OK if both do exactly the same thing, and neither throws an exception (except for OutOfMemoryError, of course) nor returns false.